# Objective C float multiplication inaccuracy

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, floating-accuracy

What I am trying to do is very simple yet the results comes up with an error:

```
    float x = 423.36;
    NSLog(@"%f", x);
    NSLog(@"%.2f", x*17719);
```

Result:

```
2012-11-12 11:19:02.096 test[2917:907] 423.359985
2012-11-12 11:19:02.098 test[2917:907] 7501515.50
```

- First question: On the first NSLog the decimal part is being changed,
  how can I keep it as it is?
- Second question: Since the decimal changes the multiplication
  process is resulting with an inaccurate product.

When calculating it with calculator I get: 7501515.84, and that is what I want to get in my app.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance!
Roy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use floats as they are inprecise for everybody. use doubles

Comment: This is only deferring the problem - try `NSLog(@"%.100f", x)` after converting `x` to a double. You'll see the same kind of error cropping up about 14 places after the decimal.

Comment: @tim sure at some point a double is inprecise too but for the given example, using a NSDecimalNumber _class_ instead of a primitive type is like 'using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut' IMO.

Answer (score 3):

1. The decimal changes because the `float` type *cannot accurately represent arbitrary numbers.* There's a finite amount of precision available to you in a float, and you need to be careful for exactly the reason that you discovered: those numbers can change around on you without warning.
2. This isn't really a question, but I'll do my best: I think what you'll want to do is find a way to represent arbitrary- (or at least higher-) precision decimal numbers to do your math on. Luckily, the iOS SDK has an answer: the [NSDecimalNumber class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which lets you deal with any number that can be expressed as `mantissa * 10 ^ exp`, where `mantissa` is up to 38 digits long. Take a look through that class reference and see if you can port your existing math to use it.

While you're at it, this would be an excellent time to read through [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/), which deals with issues like the one you discovered.

Comment: looks like a tiny bit of overhead to me I must say